# Have Firefox Session Manager backups created a huge swollen file? How to Trim Down?

Tags: backup

OBJECTIVE-- Reduce the size of accumulated backups

### My working environment-- Session Manager 6.12.1, working with Firefox 113, in Windows 7, 64bit

Searching through the boot drive on which Firefox 113 is installed, I could not find any file identified with Session Manager.
Since I regularly use Session Manager to back up my FF session files, monitoring the storage required seems important.
My objective-- to find the folder where Session Manager sessions are stored, and (if possible) trim the accumulation of session backups.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of Wiztree showing the contents of the Firefox user profile by editing your question